# How to use django session just using django-orm-standalone?

Tags: django, session, orm

I'm just creating an API using just django-orm-standalone, no web stuff so there's no request object etc..., so, how can I use django sessions to handle user login/logout/access...

Is there a "good way" to do this?

Regards.

Comment: Why don't you use DRF?(DjangoRestFramework)

Comment: I had a requirement from my employer... most use Hug Rest API because a previous version of the API but now we are using DB and my experience is using django-orm, that's why... but need to handle user's sessions or something similar to validate all requests...